# How to play a .mov from a rtsp

Tags: opencv, video, stream, rtp

i am trying to play from a wifi camera that streams on .mov file using rtsp, i get the image but it arrives distorsionated, sometimes pixelates sometimes green and sometimes without errors, while i am playing it i get the following messages in the bash:

```
    left block unavailable for requested intra mode at 0 29
[h264 @ 0x1e5af00] error while decoding MB 0 29, bytestream (-1)
[h264 @ 0x1e5b4c0] left block unavailable for requested intra mode at 0 29
[h264 @ 0x1e5b4c0] error while decoding MB 0 29, bytestream (-1)
[h264 @ 0x1e56900] left block unavailable for requested intra mode at 0 28
[h264 @ 0x1e56900] error while decoding MB 0 28, bytestream (-1)
[h264 @ 0x1e56900] left block unavailable for requested intra mode at 0 28
[h264 @ 0x1e56900] error while decoding MB 0 28, bytestream (-1)
[h264 @ 0x1ef56e0] left block unavailable for requested intra mode at 0 29
[h264 @ 0x1ef56e0] error while decoding MB 0 29, bytestream (-1)
[h264 @ 0x1e5af00] left block unavailable for requested intra mode at 0 19
```

to see the images the camera captures i am using this

```
 cv::VideoCapture capture("rtsp://192.168.1.254/sjcam.mov");
if (!capture.isOpened()) {
        //Error
    }

    cv::namedWindow("TEST", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    cv::Mat frame;

    for(int i =0; i<50000;i++) {
        if (!capture.read(frame)) {
            //Error
        }
        cv::imshow("TEST", frame);

        cv::waitKey(30);
    }
```

I do not know what else can i do, or where is the problem, i have tried to play .mov videos using opencv and i do it without problems, so i suppose i am doing something wrong with the rtsp
thanks a lot

Comment: problem partially solved, if you use libvlc you can get the images with a delay but you get them with no distortion, if you are in troubles ask me

Answer (score 1):

**if you get an error like:**

error while decoding MB

cabac decode of qscale diff failed at

left block unavailable for requested intra mode

**inicialize your VideoCapture again:**

```
#python
import cv2
address = "rtsp://login:pass@10.0.4.102:554/live/main"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(address)
while (True):
    ret, image_np = cap.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.imwrite("image.jpg", image_np)
    else:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(address)
```